# Possibility of casting android.support.v4.app.Fragment to android.app.Fragment when implementing a FragmentTabHost

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to implement a three tab screen inside a fragment (TabFragement). I am importing `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost` and `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` when creating a tabhost inside the fragment. 
When I try to call the fragment (TabFragement) using an activity, in 
 `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();` 
the method 'replace' wants to have a fragment of android.app.Fragment. 
So, how should I solve this matter? 
Any sugegstions? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the import problem you need to extends `FragmentActivity`. `FragmentActivity` was added to allow the use of `Fragments` from the support library in your `Activities`.

Also, make sure you use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead.

Comment: Yeah. A fragment activity can be used. But my actual requirement is to create a DrawerLayout and add the TabFragment to it. A DrawerLayout can be used to load fragments inside a single activity and I want the three tab screen (TabFragment) to be loaded as a fragment. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to take only Fragment instead FragmentTabhost and add tabhost to your fragmentlayout.xml and in fragment.java class take that tabhost object and create tabbar.
thats it...